Are these two separate occasions?
There are four separate accounts (in each gospel) of the woman who anoints Jesus with perfume. One identifies her as Mary, the other as a sinful woman from the city. Checked online for some commentary on this section and there is some debate about whether these are separate occasions and who the woman in question is. Please let me know if there is some clarity on this?
The relevant sections from the Gospel are: Matthew 26:1-13, Mark 14:3-9, Luke 7:36-50, John 12:1-8.

Welcome to BH. Do read the Tour [below, left] to see how this site works. It would help us if your question had a list of all the Scriptures you had in mind, then we would know that we are all working from the same references. Could you edit them in? Thanks.

the short answer as to clarity is no! Some think Mary of Bethany is also Mary Magdalene, and some think she is identical with the "sinful woman" at the house of Simon the Pharisee in Capernaum. There's also someone called Simon the Leper who may or may not be Lazarus, the brother of Mary of Bethany. Lots of questions about this already, so yours may be closed as a duplicate. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/14230/are-simon-the-pharisee-in-luke-and-simon-the-leper-in-other-gospels-the-same/32116#32116

The accounts have been so written that a certain woman cannot be identified. Such is Divine mercy.

I see the slight irony there, @Nigel J! The incident/s is/are significant enough to be recorded meticulously by 4 gospel writers, important enough to warrant Christ's " wherever this gospel is preached throughout the world, what she has done will also be told, in memory of her" (Matt 26:13, NIV). Perhaps it is not the identity of the woman, but the "beautiful" act that is highlighted here? On the other hand, if the man who carried the cross for Jesus is named, I think her name too, should find certain (unequivocal) mention too. Someday, when the voluminous books are opened?

She is being protected by not being identified. She will never be identified. Her sins are forgiven and shall never be mentioned again. Nor will we ever know who it was that committed those sins. They are gone. And you cannot prove that the woman who is identified is the same as the 'sinner' woman. I defy anyone to prove it.
